# Why is my 1440p display actually 2574 x 1447 pixels?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, display-settings

I have 3 Samsung S27H850 1440p monitors connected via DisplayPort to my NVidia RTX 2060 video card.  That should be 2560 x 1440 pixels, but it is actually 2574 x 1447 pixels.  I have the latest manufacturer drivers installed for both the video card and the monitors.  The actual coordinates of my primary monitor are (-7,0) to (2567,1447).  It looks like the entire display is used and there isn't anything being clipped off the edges.

I'm asking, partly out of curiosity, but primarily because it seems Windows 11 is reporting it as 2560 x 1440, and some applications keep track of the windows position and "adjust" the (-7,0) to (0,0) the next time it is opened, which means it is no longer in the absolute top left corner - it leaves a 7 pixel gap.

Why is the display actually 14 pixels wider and 7 pixels taller than it should be?  And how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting H and V position? https://www.manua.ls/samsung/s27h850/manual?p=35 Also check other settings, e.g., Picture Size .

Comment: I tried, but it totally screwed up the monitor.  I had to reset it.  The positions seem to have to do with PIP.